# Why is the output a question mark in a box instead of a number?

Tags: c++, loops, output

I'm trying to write a program that alerts a user if a certain puppy owner has a puppy that is beyond a certain distance from the puppy owner.

Specifically, the following program:

- first asks the user to input the location of the owner, namely inputting 2 integers `a` and `b`.
- then asks the user to input the number of puppies the owner has. This is a positive integer `n`.
- for each puppy `i` of the n puppies, the program asks the user to input the location of puppy i. This is 2 integers `x` and `y`, both of which are of course dependent on i.
- If puppy i is calculated to have reached a distance greater than 10 units from its owner, then the program should inform the user by printing i.
- Finally, the program should tell the user the total number of puppies whose numbers have been printed. This number is represented by the variable `count`, a positive integer.

The following is an example case

> Inputs:
>   (Owner location) 2 1
>   (number puppies) 4
>   (location puppies) (15 15), (14 -2), (1 3), (0 4)
>
> Outputs:
>   Puppy 1 and Puppy 2 too far away
>   Total 2 puppies too far away

When I try to run the program, the program outputs a question mark instead of the instead of the `i`'s. What did I do wrong, please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string puppies;

    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;

    int n;
    cin>>n;

    int i,x,y,count=0;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
      cin>>x>>y;
      int dist;
      dist=abs(a-x)+abs(b-y);
      if (dist>10){
        count++;
        puppies += i;
      }
    }
    if (count==1){
      cout<<"Puppy "<<puppies[0]<<" too far away"<<endl;
      cout<<"Total "<< count <<" puppy too far away";
    }
    if (count>1){
      int j;
      for (j=0;j<=(count-2);j++){
        cout<<"Puppy "<<puppies[j]<<" and"<<" ";
      }
      cout<<"Puppy "<<puppies[count-1]<<" too far away"<<endl;
      cout<<"Total "<< count <<" puppies too far away";
    }
    if (count==0){
      cout<<"No puppies too far away";
    }
}
```

---

Here is the copied output (for the same case as above)

> Puppy  and Puppy  too far away
>   Total 2 puppies too far awayPress any key to continue . . .

Here is a screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFJaY.png)

Comment: `program outputs a question mark instead of the instead of the i's` it outputs only a single question mark? Can you please post the exact output.

Comment: @KamilCuk Edited. Thanks

Comment: @Kira Outstanding. Outstanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to use a `std::string` as a container for numbers. It can do that for small enough ones, sure, but you'll probably want to switch to `std::vector<int>`.

The issue you're actually observing is that `puppies[0]` is a `char`, which in `std::cout << puppies[0]` is interpreted as a single text character, which in your case is a low codepoint corresponding to a non-printable character, hence the question mark displayed by your shell. You can fix it by converting explicitly with `static_cast<int>(puppies[0])`, but again using a suitable container for actual numbers would be more advisable.

Comment: Quentin, can you help @Kira with [How to interlace two array lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899857/how-to-interlace-two-array-lists)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> puppies += i;
> ```

If you take a look at the overload set, you'll find that there is no overload for `int`. However, there is an overload for `char`. All integer types are implicitly convertible to other integer types, and in this case `int` is converted to `char`. The character that is appended to the string is the one which is represented by the integer value. What integer value represent what character depends on the character set that your system uses.

You may have intended to append the integer in a textual representation instead. You can convert an integer to a string for example using `std::to_string`.

That said, using string for this purpose seems backwards, as you don't appear to use it as a character string, but more like an array of integers. As such, a vector of integers might be a more sensible choice.